# Example of a commutative, cocommutative, $p$-torsion Hopf algebra which is dualizable but not self-dual?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory, quantum-groups, hopf-algebras

Let $C$ be a symmetric monoidal category with split idempotents, and let $H$ be a Hopf algebra object in $C$. If $H$ is dualizable as an object of $C$, then $H^\vee = L \otimes H$ for some $\otimes$-invertible object $L$. This says that $H$ is *almost* self-dual as an object of $C$. (In fact $L$ is given by a certain explicit retract of $H^\vee$, and its inverse is the dual retract of $H$). This fact is due to [Takeuchi](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0022-4049(97)00207-7) I believe, building on work of Larson and Sweedler.

**Terminology:** Here I'm using the notion of a [dual object in a monoidal category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_object), and I write $X^\vee$ for the dual of $X$. Recall that when $C$ is the category of vector spaces over a field $k$, this just means that $X$ is finite-dimensional. I say that $X$ is *self-dual* if there is some isomorphism $X^\vee \cong X$ in $C$ (I don't require any further coherence). And I'm always talking about self-duality *in $C$* -- I don't care about self-duality *as a Hopf algebra*.

**Examples:** There are plenty of examples of dualizable Hopf algebras which are not self-dual -- for example, the cohomology of a compact Lie group $G$ over a field $k$ is a Hopf algebra in the derived category of $k$ which is dualizable, but not self-dual unless $G$ is finite. Indeed, $\Sigma^\infty_+ G$ is a Hopf algebra in spectra with a Spanier-Whitehead dual which is not self-dual unless $G$ is finite. Here $L = S^n$ where $n$ is the dimension of $G$.

The most exotic example of a dualizable, $p$-torsion Hopf algebra I can think of is $L_{K(n)} \Sigma^\infty_+ K(\mathbb Z / p,m)$ -- the $K(n)$-local stable Eilenberg-MacLane space. This example is self-dual as an object of the $K(n)$-local category.

**Lack of examples:** However, there are no infinite compact Lie groups which are abelian and $p$-torsion in the sense that the $p$-power map is trivial, i.e. $\nabla^p \Delta^p = \eta \varepsilon$ where $\eta$ is the unit, $\varepsilon$ is the counit, $\nabla^p$ is the $p$-fold multiplication, and $\Delta^p$ is the $p$-fold comultiplication. This leads to my

> **Questions:**
>
> 1. What is an example of a Hopf algebra object $H$ in a symmetric monoidal category $C$ which is commutative and cocommutative, $p$-torsion for some $p$, and dualizable as an object of $C$, but *not* self-dual as an object of $C$?
> 2. Or is there some reason why this can't happen?
> 3. As a potentially slightly easier question: is there an example of a commutative, cocommutative Hopf algebra $H$ in some $C$ which is $p$-torsion and dualizable such that $L$ is not the unit object of $C$, even if it turns out that $H^\vee = L \otimes H$ is still isomorphic to $H$?

Note that I always mean duality *as an object of $C$* rather than as a Hopf algebra object in $C$. So I'm asking for $H$ to not be self-dual as an object of $C$, which is *stronger* than asking for $H$ to not be self-dual as a Hopf algebra object.

P.S. If anybody has any better tag ideas, feel free to modify them.

P.P.S. Takeuchi actually constructs $L$ as an equalizer of two maps, but I assert that $L^\vee$ can equivalently be defined as the fixed points of following endomorphism of $H$ (which is automatically idempotent) and that $L$ is the fixed points of the dual idempotent:

$$((ev_H \circ \sigma_{H^\vee,H})\otimes 1_H)\circ (1_{H^\vee} \otimes (\Delta \circ \nabla)) \circ (coev_H \otimes 1_H)$$

where $ev_H: H\otimes H^\vee \to I$ is the evaluation, $\sigma_{H,H^\vee}: H \otimes H^\vee \to H^\vee \otimes H$ is the braiding, $\Delta$ and $\nabla$ are the comultiplication and multiplication on $H$, respectively, and $coev_H : I \to H^\vee \otimes H$ is the coevaluation (here $I$ is the unit object of the monoidal category $C$). It's best to draw as a string diagram, I think.

A similar idempotent-splitting works for any Hopf module over $H$.

Comment: Isn't the $L_{K(n)} K(\mathbb{Z}/p,n)$ being a hopf algebra kind of a red heering here? In any $\infty$-semiadditive symmetric monoidal category all $\pi$-finite spaces will be self-dual.

Comment: @SaalHardali Exactly. It's a "near-example" just like the examples coming from Lie groups. Maybe the point is that all the examples I know seem to be red herrings.

Comment: I feel like many times the interesting notion of duality for hopf algebras is different than the symmetric monoidal one. I'm thinking of cartier duality and maybe even its chromatic variant for p-finite eilenberg maclane spaces in the $K(n)$-local category.

Comment: For instance when $p>2$ and $n$ is odd and $1<k<n$ then $K(\mathbb{Z}/p,n-k)$ is kind of a cartier dual of $K(\mathbb{Z}/p,k)$ in the $K(n)$-local category (at least at the level of dieudonne modules it becomes actually true - to make this work spectrally you need to set up the correct framework which I don't remember how to do currently). In particular they will not be self (cartier) dual.